# What kind of setup (IDE et al) do I need to run IronPython unit tests of C#.NET developed assemblies?

Tags: .net, python, ironpython

I'm attempting to learn IronPython, to broaden my .NET horizons. I want to be able to use Python to write the unit-tests for my next personal project. So being able to access C#.NET assemblies from my Python code is necessary. I also wanted an IDE with auto-complete and smart indenting.  PyScripter seemed like a good option, but can I run IronPython from it, and can I link to .NET assemblies from it?

**What kind of setup (IDE et al) do I need to run IronPython unit tests of C#.NET developed assemblies?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good link to an article about different IDE's and how they work with IronPython:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/tools-and-ides.shtml

Answer (score 1):

See Michael Foord's website [for IDE](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_Website.shtml) and [unittest](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2009_06_13.shtml) also discover. And many IronPython articles and the book IronPython in Action
and his tweets save you having to hunt for IronPython references

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Frood himself uses Wing IDE.

But, if its on Windows, why not VS?

Comment: I looked at Wing IDE the personal edition.  It didn't look good.  And I have heard a lot of bad stuff about the Python IDE for VS

Comment: Wing IDE professional is not something I plan on paying for yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using Eclipse with PyDev which has support for IronPython

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio. I use IronPython Studio integrated with VS2008. But I feel that it has very poor intellisense for Python.